# since HttpExchange require that sendResponseHeaders(int,long) must be before getResponseBody(), how do I handle transmitting file?

Tags: java

The following code is no longer feasible

```
server.createContext("/", exchange -> {
 URL url = new URL("");
 try (final BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream()); final BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(exchange.getResponseBody())) {

 } catch (IOException e) {

 }
});
server.start();
```

The reason is that `sendResponseHeaders(int,long)` must be before `getResponseBody()` and the `long` in `sendResponseHeaders(int,long)` is the length of content to be written into ResponseBody...but now I cannot figure out the value.
so what should I do?

The size of the file is unknown: it can be smaller than 1MB but also can be bigger than 200MB, so creating a big enough byte array cannot be accepted. To convert the file to String or bytes directly without buffer cannot be accepted too.
What can I do?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue - in my case, helped to read the documentation in more detail...

> responseLength - if > 0, specifies a fixed response body length and
> that exact number of bytes must be written to the stream acquired from
> getResponseBody(), or else if equal to 0, then chunked encoding is
> used, and an arbitrary number of bytes may be written. if <= -1, then
> no response body length is specified and no response body may be
> written.

So zero should work here as well